# How to debug not-triggering callback function when using an external SDK?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sockets, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I'm trying to implement a project what uses [NatNet SDK](http://www.naturalpoint.com/optitrack/products/natnet-sdk/), an SDK for connecting to an optical tracking camera software.

My problem is the following: I'm trying to use the simplest possible example to connect to a server, but it behaves differently when I compile it under VS2010 and when I run the supplied exe. The SDK solutions and compiled versions are from VS2005.

There is a single line in the program to set up a callback.

```
theClient->SetDataCallback( DataHandler, theClient );   // this function will receive data from the server
```

The problem is that if I compile the project under VS2010, it compiles fine and runs fine, but the callback doesn't get triggered, the client believes like nothing happens.

If I re-compile a test-server application, the new, compiled client works with the new, compiled server.

Here is a small summary of how the different compiled client and servers function.

- original client - ARENA => OK
- original client - original server => OK
- original client - VS2010 compiled server => not working, only receiving a single line
- VS2010 compiled client - ARENA => not working, not receiving anything
- VS2010 compiled client - original server => not working, not
- receiving anything VS2010 compiled client - VS 2010 compiled server => OK

I'm really not experienced on this level of Visual Studio version differences and I don't know how could I debug a non-triggering callback. Since I'm forced to connect to the supplied software (ARENA), I cannot just recompile it, like I did with the sample server solution.

Can you help in the following questions?

- What can be the difference between the VS2005 and VS2010 what makes these callback functions not work with versions compiled from each other?
- Is it possible to fix it with a simple build setting? If not, how can I debug where the problem happens?
- And finally, would you recommend me using a pure socket-based implementation instead of the SDK given that they've provided one and that it seems that the SDK hasn't been updated for a couple of Visual Studio versions now?

Comment: Please, provide the prototype of the callback function. And the types used in arguments and return value.

Comment: It's closed source with only these header files. I tried to get some information out of these, but it all seems just data oriented. http://pastebin.com/WHzfixtX and http://pastebin.com/bJR0N0Aa

Comment: Are you sure the VS2005 samples work fine? Did you try it for yourself?

Comment: I don't have VS2005, but the compiled exe files what they've given work fine, and the solutions are for VS2005. If you believe this is too vendor specific problem then I can leave it and just implement the pure socket-based way.

Comment: I believe this should behave the same in VS2005 and VS2010. For now you don't have a clear scenario which works under VS2005, but doesn't work under VS2010.

Comment: I've just checked in a VS2005 environment in VirtualBox. It's the same as the compiled files. So I can confirm, that the project works differently when compiled in VS2005 vs VS2010. Also, it seems that the bug is somehow related to UDP unicast vs. multicast. If I set the VS2005 compiled version to multicast and the VS2010 to unicast it seems to work OK. Like if the winsocks implementation changed the values between versions.